# Extacting stresses along path for several odbs in abaqus

Tags: python, abaqus

I have modeled 5 models in abaqus. Now I want to open the odbs by Abaqus python script and extract data in different paths. But I can't open the odbs together. How can write to open all the odbs together? I could create paths, but how can I extract the stresses from the same path for my 5 model? Thanks in advance.

```
import visualization
from abaqus import *
from odbAccess import openOdb
#-----------------------------
l1 = [200.0,200.0]  
height = [1000.0] 
l2 = [200.0,200.0]  
T1 = [20.0,25.0]   
delta_t= [20.0,25.0]
multiplied_list = [element * 4 for element in delta_t]
partition_datum_plane_XY = [750.0,1080.0,1250.0,1786.0]  
#------------------------------

# list of ODB-Files
odb_names = ['Para_Analysis_H_1000_W_200_t1_40_T1_20.odb','Para_Analysis_H_1000_W_200_t1_50_T1_30.odb',
'Para_Analysis_H_1000_W_200_t1_30_T1_15.odb']  # Dummy list 
path='./'
odbs = [1]*len(odb_names); 
vips = [1]*len(odb_names); 
for s,odb_name in enumerate(odb_names):    
    print('\n\nlooping for %s ODB...'%odb_names)     
    vips[s] = session.Viewport(name='Girder Viewport_%d'%(s+1))     
    odbs[s] = session.openOdb(name=odb_name)

    path=session.Path(name='Path-1', type=POINT_LIST, expression=((l1[i], T1[i],partition_datum_plane_XY[0]), 
    (l1[i], T1[i],partition_datum_plane_XY[1]), (l1[i], t1[i],multiplied_list[i]+partition_datum_plane_XY[1]),
    (l1[i], t1[i],partition_datum_plane_XY[2])))
    
    pth=session.path['Path-1']
    vips[s].setValues(displayedObject=odbs[s])
    newXYData=session.XYDataFromPath(name=xyName,path=pth,
    includeIntersections=TRUE,
    shape=UNDEFORMED,
    labelType=TRUE_DISTANCE,
    step=1,
    frame=1,
    variable=(('S',INTEGRATION_POINT,((COMPONENT, 'S11' ),)),))
    session.writeXYReport(fileName='%s.txt'%name, xyData=(newXYData,))
```

Comment: I think, you can just loop over odb names. Like, ```odb_names = ['job-1.odb','Job-2.odb','Job-3.odb']

# Dummy list with length of odb_names list. In this we can store the ODB objects
odbs = [1]*len(odb_names); vips = [1]*len(odb_names);
for s,odb_name in enumerate(odb_names):
    print('\n\nlooping for %s ODB...'%odb_name)
    vips[s] = session.Viewport(name='Girder Viewport_%d'%(s+1))
    odbs[s] = session.openOdb(name=odb_name)```.  Also, in your code, you are creating the `Path` with same name, I don't think that's correct.

Comment: perfect coding for getting odbs. I have tried to loop over the defined path but could not get result. How to successfully execute the loop over this path?

Comment: Could you just specify the error you're getting? It will be easy to provide you with solution.

Comment: I set the code again on the top of page. I got IndentationError: unexpected indent on  path=session.Path(name='Path-1', type=POINT_LIST, expression=(). There is a problem of finding the coordinates of the paths. I tried with different approch but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abaqus stores some specific type of objects in the `Repository`. Hence, whenever you create these objects, the name of that object must be unique. Example of Abaqus objects, `xy plot`, `viewports`, `paths`, `steps`, `models`, etc.. 
Secondly, to use Abaqus specific constants, such as `DEFORMED`, UNDEFORMED`(capital variables), you have to import`abaqusConstants ` module.
I just looked at your code and made few changes.

```
import odbAccess
from abaqus import *
from abaqusConstants import *
from viewerModules import *
from driverUtils import executeOnCaeStartup

#Variables
l1 = [200.0,200.0,200.0,200.0,200.0]  #Bottom flange length
height = [1000.0,1000.0,1000.0,1000.0,1000.0] #Total height
X_coord=0.0
Y_coord=0.0
Z_coord=0.0

# odb_names --> list of ODB names for which to access the data from
odb_names = ['Para_Analysis_H_1000_W_200_t1_40_T1_20.odb',
             'Para_Analysis_H_1000_W_200_t1_50_T1_30.odb',
             'Para_Analysis_H_1000_W_200_t1_30_T1_15.odb']
viewp = session.currentViewportName
viewport = session.viewports[viewp]
viewport.makeCurrent()
viewport.maximize()

# Creating the paths - You can change the expressions for the pah.
# These paths are specific to session and NOT to ODB. Hence, if you created once, 
# you can use it for any number of ODBs. Path name must be UNIQUE.
for i in range(len(l1)):
    session.Path(name='Path-1-Bottom-Upper-Side_%d'%(i+1), type=POINT_LIST, expression=
    ((l1[i],Y_coord,Z_coord), (l1[i]/2,Y_coord,Z_coord),))

    # session.Path(name='Path-1', type=POINT_LIST, expression=((l1[i], T1[i],partition_datum_plane_XY[0]), 
    #     (l1[i], T1[i],partition_datum_plane_XY[1]), (l1[i], t1[i],multiplied_list[i]+partition_datum_plane_XY[1]),
    #     (l1[i], t1[i],partition_datum_plane_XY[2])))

# Dummy list with length of odb_names list. In this we can store the ODB objects
odbs = [1]*len(odb_names);  count_plots = 0
for s,odb_name in enumerate(odb_names):
    print('\n\nlooping for %s ODB...'%odb_name)
    # Opening the ODB
    odbs[s] = session.openOdb(name=odb_name)

    # Setting the ODB to the viewport in DEFORMED state
    viewport.setValues(displayedObject=odbs[s])
    viewport.odbDisplay.display.setValues(plotState=(DEFORMED,))
    # Setting S11 component of stress tot he viewport
    viewport.odbDisplay.setPrimaryVariable(variableLabel='S', 
       outputPosition=INTEGRATION_POINT, refinement=(COMPONENT,'S11'))
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    for i in range(len(l1)):
        count_plots = count_plots + 1
        print('Creating plots | %d'%count_plots)
        # Accessing the path created before
        pth = session.paths['Path-node_%d'%(i+1)]
        # Creating the xy plot.
        xyp = session.XYPlot('XYPlot-S11-%d'%(count_plots))
        chartName = xyp.charts.keys()[0]
        chart = xyp.charts[chartName]
        xy1 = xyPlot.XYDataFromPath(name='xy_data_%d'%(count_plots),path=pth, includeIntersections=True,
           pathStyle=PATH_POINTS, shape=UNDEFORMED,labelType=TRUE_DISTANCE_Z)

        #Plot curve
        c1 = session.Curve(xyData=xy1)
        chart.setValues(curvesToPlot=(c1, ), )
        viewport.setValues(displayedObject=xyp)
```

After seeing your code, I feel there is lot to learn for you regarding the Abaqus Python scripting (pardon me if I am wrong). To get started, you can read `Abaqus Scripting User's Guide` and later you can explore `Abaqus Scripting Reference Guide`.

Comment: Wonderful explanation and suggestion.Helps me a lot that cannot be described. It's very true that I am struggling with very limited abaqus python scripting knowledge and vast project work. I have started to read Abaqus Scripting User's Guide. A big thanks to you.

Comment: Hi, the problem i face is that, even if the paths are there in the seesion and the script works it gives me 'VisError: No results could be found for xy data extraction from path' as it cannot find the certain path for odbs. I found in the documentation XYDataFromPath(...)method but could not solve the proble. If possible can you give some idea?

Comment: There could be multiple reasons for this error. Path may be lying outside the mesh. For this you could change the path definition. You can try with `DEFORMED` and `UNDEFORMED` shape. or you could check the label type. One of my favorite trick is to try doing this manually using Abaqus/CAE GUI and try to modify the code as per our need. You can refer "Viewing results along a path" topic in Abaqus/CAE User's Guide.